# Data downloaded while upgrading to Windows 10?

Tags: wireless, network-core, network-access

Here is case:
I have many PC's/Laptops which has windows 7 or windows 8.
I wanted to upgrade all of those machines to Windows 10. All we have is wireless connectivity. No ethernet cables are used for this upgrade.
At the same time i wanted to check how much data is downloaded at each PC/Laptop?

I thought of using any third party software that catches amount of data downloaded, but in OS upgrades, third party softwares wont work.
Second, i thought of using information from WAP(Wireless Access Point) a particular PC/Laptop is associated with, but we dont have that luxury to ask for WAP data.

Any other thought would be really appreciated.

Note: I dont find any relevant tags either for this question. Suggest some tag as well so that we can ask appropriate experts.

Comment: You could look at the counters on the switch ports where the WAPs are connected. NetFlow could probably give you what you want if you have that set up.

Comment: @RonMaupin Can you tell more details about it? Bit more description?

Comment: You will need to edit your question to provide more detail about your network: router/switch/WAP models, how they are connected, etc. Configurations and a diagram would be good, too.

Comment: Please visit the help section, about what's on-topic here. If you "*don't have the luxury to ask for WAP data*" it sounds a lot like you fail the "*under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to answer your question);*" condition. Or else you have a consumer-grade WAP setup that does not provide data, and which is likewise off-topic here (might be on-topic at superuser.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes. I agree.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless I have a control over network, I can not find it.